# Laravel Sanctum with SPA: Best practice for setting the CSRF cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

Currently, my SPA is simple and has only a contact form. The form data is sent to the backend. I have installed Laravel Sanctum for that.

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((response) => {
     axios.post('api/contact')
          .then((response) => {
              //doing stuff
          });
});
```

This works perfectly fine. However, I was wondering. **Where and which time in your SPA do you fire the initial request to get the CSRF cookie?** (`axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')`)

My first thoughts were:

- Every time the page is mounted/loaded
- Only when you receive a `419` and you attempt to refresh the token and retry the previous request
- You don't fire any API requests, only when the user tries to log in and only then you are requesting a cookie (in my case I don't have any user authentification)
- For each API request, you wrap it with `axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')` around

Answer (score 5):

So for future readers, I chose:

`Only when you receive a 419 and you attempt to refresh the token and retry the previous request`

For that, I'm using the package [axios-auth-refresh](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh).

My settings look like that

```
//bootstrap.js

import axios from 'axios';
import createAuthRefreshInterceptor from 'axios-auth-refresh';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.GRIDSOME_BACKEND_URL;

const refreshAuthLogic = (failedRequest) => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((response) => Promise.resolve());

createAuthRefreshInterceptor(axios, refreshAuthLogic, { statusCodes: [419] });

window.axios = axios;
```

Comment: Thanks! `const refreshAuthLogic = async (): Promise<void> => { await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie') }` is a valid typescript alternative.